# Search for a string containing a string access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vba

I need help with Search for a string containing a string ( which will display all the texts containing that text example : searching for strings containing Syringe displays all the syringes , like syringe 10ML , syringe 20ML , ABL syringe)

here is my code so far my project is connected to a access database.

```
        Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

        Dim stock As String
        stock = cmbSearch.Text

        Select Case stock
            Case "Stock Level"
                Me.Sheet1BindingSource.Filter = "Stock = '" & txtSearch.Text & "'"
            Case "Description"
                Me.Sheet1BindingSource.Filter = "Description = '" & txtSearch.Text & "'"
            Case "Article"
                Me.Sheet1BindingSource.Filter = "Article = '" & txtSearch.Text & "'"
            Case "Merche Cat"
                Me.Sheet1BindingSource.Filter = "Merche Category = '" & txtSearch.Text & "'"
            Case "Merche Dis"
                Me.Sheet1BindingSource.Filter = "Merche Description = '" & txtSearch.Text & "'"
        End Select

    End Sub
End Class
```

I want that as Description as the description of the items contain same like Syringe.

Comment: use like instead of = operator, for instance `"Stock like '%" & txtsearch.text & "%'"`

Comment: Case "Description"
                Me.Sheet1BindingSource.Filter = "Description '%" & txtSearch.Text & "%'"

Doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Using `LIKE` in Access VBA is different from SQL Server - 
Use `LIKE` with wildcards,
 for instance:

```
"Stock LIKE '*" & txtsearch.text & "*'"
```

Comment: While Jet SQL (the SQL dialect used by Access) also uses `Like` this way, in this case it's because of VBA, not Access.

Comment: @ZevSpitz, Nutella is in VB.NET so I assume he is using JET behind the scenes of ADO.NET